# How to delete a referenced file?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In an 6.2.26 installation we have the following problem:
an editor wants to delete a file, which is not used any more.

if I click on the delete icon I primary get the warning about 3 references while in the list only 2 are shown:
[image]

if I agree I get the error message:
[image]

Trying to identify the problem in the database results in strange findings.
The data is no straight include but a two level IRRE construct (#1) and there once were workspaces installed (meanwhile removed)

1. so there are two references shown in the file list module we can only find one reference (or two references in case of the file with the shown four references)
2. the mm-records are deleted (`deleted = 1`)  and show usage of workspaces (`t3ver_id = 1`, `t3ver_label = 'First draft version'`)
3. after removing of these records and following cleanup-task (`Dateiabstraktionsschicht: Speicherindex aktualisieren (scheduler)`) there were no differences in the list or count of the references

How can we cleanup the database?
how can the editor delete the file?

(#1)

```
tt_content  
    +-(IRRE)-> tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_downloadbox  
        +-(IRRE)-> tx_downloadlinks_domain_model_links
            +-> sys_file_references
                +-> sys_file
```

Answer (score 1):

These are probably references in `sys_ref`. Try to update the `sys_ref` table. Is one of the low-level cli commands